# change TEXT to display in excel via vba

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to change the text to display of all the hyperlinks in a sheet?

All I want to do it is run a macro to trim the the existing TEXT to Display to 5 chrs only?
At the mo, my text to display is really big text string something like "21253.bla bla bla.wla wla wla. dah dah dah.jpg" and I only want to display 21253

Is this even possible?
Regards
Shei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the links on the sheets and use the left function to trim the text to display.  Example below

```
Dim hl As Hyperlink
For Each hl In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
    hl.TextToDisplay = Left(hl.TextToDisplay, 5)
Next
```